# Proper 'cleartool mkview' for ClearCase Snapshot view creation

Tags: view, clearcase, cleartool, snapshot-view

Good afternoon,

Seems like I am somewhat stuck in CC-land these days, but I have one (hopefully) final question regarding proper CC-handling:

When using the CC View Creation Wizard, I can create a proper Snapshot view on my machine perfectly fine, however when trying to do the same with the mkview command, it fails...

Using the the view creation wizard results into the (working) following view:

```
cleartool> lsview battjo6r_view2
  battjo6r_view2       \\Eh40yd4c\Views\battjo6r_view2.vws
cleartool> lsview -long battjo6r_view2
Tag: battjo6r_view2
  Global path: \\Eh40yd4c\Views\battjo6r_view2.vws
  Server host: Eh40yd4c
  Region: CT_WORK
  Active: NO
  View tag uuid:f34cf43f.b4d048df.845d.ed:21:a2:9c:45:ff
View on host: Eh40yd4c
View server access path: D:\Views\battjo6r_view2.vws
View uuid: f34cf43f.b4d048df.845d.ed:21:a2:9c:45:ff
View attributes: snapshot
View owner: WW005\battjo6r
```

However, when trying to create the view manually via

```
mkview -snapshot -tag battjo6r_view2 -vws \\Eh40yd4c\Views\battjo6r_view2.vws -host Eh40yd4c -hpath D:\Views\battjo6r_view2.vws -gpath \\Eh40yd4c\Views\battjo6r_view2.vws battjo6r_view2
```

... I get the following error:

```
cleartool> mkview -snapshot -tag battjo6r_view2 -vws \\Eh40yd4c\Views\battjo6r_view2.vws -host Eh40yd4c -hpath D:\Views\battjo6r_view2.vws -gpath \\Eh40yd4c\Views\battjo6r_view2.vws battjo6r_view2
Created view.
Host-local path: Eh40yd4c:D:\Views\battjo6r_view2.vws
Global path:     \\Eh40yd4c\Views\battjo6r_view2.vws
cleartool: Error: Unable to find view by uuid:6f99f7ae.6a5d40e4.ba32.37:8e:e5:a4:ed:18, last known at "<viewhost>:<stg_path>".
cleartool: Error: Unable to establish connection to snapshot view "6f99f7ae.6a5d40e4.ba32.37:8e:e5:a4:ed:18": ClearCase object not found
cleartool: Warning: Unable to open snapshot view "D:\SnapShotViews\battjo6r_view2".
cleartool: Error: Unable to create snapshot view "battjo6r_view2".
Removing the view ...
```

Any idea why this is happening? Am I missing something?

Comment: Any news on that "`mkview`" command output? If you still have error messages, leave them as a comment to my answer and I will have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is usually due to the albd not running.
Actually, it *is* running, but ClearCase tries to contact the wrong host.

Here: `Host-local path: Eh40yd4c:D:\Views\battjo6r_view2.vws` is highly suspicious.

Try:

```
mkview -snapshot -tag battjo6r_view2 -vws \\Eh40yd4c\Views\battjo6r_view2.vws -host Eh40yd4c -hpath \\Eh40yd4c\Views\battjo6r_view2.vws -gpath \\Eh40yd4c\Views\battjo6r_view2.vws battjo6r_view2
```

That is: hpath = gpath.

or, if the first command fails, also (it is simpler and may work)

```
mkview -snapshot -tag battjo6r_view2 -vws \\Eh40yd4c\Views\battjo6r_view2.vws battjo6r_view2
```

Hopefully, ClearCase could determine for itself the host, hpath and gpath.

Comment: @Jörg Glad I could help: that one is a "classic" (I lost quite a bit of time the first time I stumble upon it)

Answer (score 0):

```
cleartool mkview -snapshot -tag <tag_name> -vws \\<computer_name>\<views_folder>\<view_name> <path_of_localstorage>
```

For details you may follow [this link](https://iffetoguz.com/2016/10/04/creating-snapshot-view-via-clearcase-cleartool-commands/).