# How can I export latest sources from ClearCase without creating any private areas or anything (like with svn export command)?

Tags: clearcase

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exporting sources from ClearCase?

The surest way is a [snapshot view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207409/proper-cleartool-mkview-for-clearcase-snapshot-view-creation) on a dedicated workstation: since a snapshot view has its storage (the equivalent of the `.svn` directories) *outside* the said view, that means the resulting directory is clean.

Then you can take this tree, compress it and transfer it whenever you want, (like a workstation without any VCS)

Comment: I was trying to make a snapshot view but it complained that storage server is using different operating system and failed. Why does it have to store something on server?

Comment: You can specify the view storage by using an explicit path: just use a directory on your computer you can access through a share. That means you have a ClearCase server (view server) installed

Comment: It needs to have a view storage because it checkout files and references to date if checkin files are stored within. That way the snapshot view can detect hijacked files (files modified without being checked out first)

Answer (score 0):

Use a snapshot view. Update the config spec in such a way that it selects the latest version of all elements from the main branch.

Copy the folder recursively to another folder say c:\svntemp

Import the contents in c:\svntemp\ in to SVN.

For each branch that you have you need to follow this procedure