# How can I generate offline diff output between two views?

Tags: version-control, diff, clearcase, offline

I am working on analyzing different files between two views in Clearcase. I need to generate output so that I can do this task without an internet connection. What I would like is to run a command that recursively walks through each view and generates a merge/diff output file for each change from view A to view B. This can work like a merge, except that I don't actually want to make any changes.

How can I set this up so that I can continue looking at diff output amidst all of these files while offline? I am using Clearcase, but if another tool can do the same work comparing two directory structures, that's fine, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"diff output amidst all of these files while offline?": it sounds as of you are using two dynamic views here (which do need a network connection with the ClearCase Vob server to display any file)

For a task like this, I switch to two **[snapshot views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923328/what-are-the-differences-between-a-snapshot-view-and-a-dynamic-view/2925378#2925378)** (which at least download the file on the local disk), and then use any **[file comparison tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3435866/comparing-views-in-clearcase/3435880#3435880)** out there (WinMerge, BeyondCompare, KDiff3).

Or I will use git ([created directly within the ClearCase views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342131/how-to-bridge-git-to-clearcase/2342164#2342164)) to [compare the two directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460558/creating-a-patch-file-from-a-diff-of-2-folders).

Comment: Thanks! I figured out that I could do it using KDiff3 + snapshot views after talking with my co-worker. This is what I ended up doing. (KDiff3, incidentally, has much nicer output for what I was doing than the default clearcase diff tool, though it takes a little getting used to.)

Comment: @RMorrisey: and don't forget you ca use custom diff tools with ClearCase. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375398/any-way-to-use-a-custom-diff-tool-with-cleartool-clearcase/375437#375437