# Show differences between files on two branches unrelated to present view

Tags: branch, diff, clearcase

I'm working on a (GNU/Linux) system with a ClearCase client installed. On this system, people don't always have views correspond to every branch; and have different "branch trees" for different files.

Now, given that I have no relevant view set as the present working view, or that the PWV is irrelevant to the branches I'm interested in - how do I generate a diff between the files existing on two specific branches?

In this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2786120/1593077

there are assumptions about the PWV being relevant, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way would be to create two [snapshot views](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3631073/6309) dedicated for that task:

- one with a config spec selecting branch1
- one with a config spec selecting branch2

Then a Linux tool like [kdiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) (or at least a simple `diff -qr dir1 dir2`) would display the difference between files list and file contents.

Comment: That's not that simple ... certainly not something you do with a single command. And it takes up a lot of disk space if there are a lot of files on the two branches

Comment: Then use dynamic views, but yes, there is no simple one command for that