# unable to build ant with Clearcase on VMware

Tags: locking, clearcase, directory

So here is the problem.

I have a local snapshot in my local windows system and i run my ant script and it builds.

I have build system which is also winxp but its a vmware built inside ubuntu. i have also a snapshot there too in winxp , and my script runs against this. But clearcase doesnt allow to write anything on this folder and build fails. Tried and tired of changing everything thats possible.

I did try one more option, like copying snapshot from my local windows system to vmware winxp and run it from there, and it works cool. Coz clearcase doesnt hold any lock. Unable to figure out how to fix this.

Any thoughts friends ?.

Answer (score 1):

ClearCase shouldn't prevent the creation of *private* files in a *snapshot* view.
[A snapshot view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923328/what-are-the-differences-between-a-snapshot-view-and-a-dynamic-view/2925378#2925378) is like a SVN workspace: a collection if files copied on the hard-drive (as opposed to dynamic views which allows for network-access to the same elements)

So I suspect your script fails when it tries to checkout and/or "add to source control" elements.
I which case you need to make sure of the:

- user characteristics (`CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP`)
- view protect ("`cleartool lsview -l -full -pro`")

If you have those informations, plus any specific error message, you can add them to your question and leave a comment on this answer. I will then update it accordingly.