# Setup Project in VS2008 on Win7 with ClearCase not building?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-7, clearcase

I get "`Unrecoverable error`" when I try to build my project which contains a `SETUP` for creating an `MSI`.
I'm using VS2008 on Win7 while under ClearCase.
My ClearCase view is on a shared drive.
If I move my project local it builds just fine. Seems to be a permission/trust issue with the Network Disk where my source code resides.

I've tried numerous approaches from items I've found... none seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of project, where network access can be an issue, I would always recommend **[snapshot view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2923328/what-are-the-differences-between-a-snapshot-view-and-a-dynamic-view)** (which is the equivalent of you moving said project "local").
Shared network paths or dynamic views wouldn't be the best options here.

Comment: That seems to work fine but in the future we have a need for Dynamic Views since it's a large project that multiple people might need to build.  Oh and thanks for your help!