# code synchronize between clearcase and svn

Tags: svn, clearcase

I have a requirement to use clearsvn(from collabnet) to synchronize the code between two remote repositories CLEARCASE and SVN. I am not able to understand even after reading the manual on how it works and how to implement it. the code is in clearcase and svn side , its an empty repository . Now, I have to use clearsvn to synchronize the code between the vob and svn repository.

ClearCase(7.1) and SVN(version 1.6) remote  servers both are on Linux(RHEL 6.4) and I am running Windows 7 with ClearCase remote client on my machine.

I have to synchronize one way i.e. I take updated clearcase code whenever there is a code change everytime to svn repository.

I just need a starting point as i am confused on how to start?

Comment: What is the problem? What error message do you see? Do you need to synchronize in both directions? What version of ClearCase and svn do you have? On what OS those (ClearCase and svn) servers are?

Comment: Please find my post updated

Comment: I don't know anything about clearsvn, but it might be worth reading this: [Mirror a Subversion Repository](http://www.microhowto.info/howto/mirror_a_subversion_repository.html)

Answer (score 0):

The [ClearSVN tool](http://clearsvn.open.collab.net/) seems to be deprecated and no longer actively maintained.
The last commit for that [tool source dates from 4 years ago](http://clearsvn.open.collab.net/source/browse/clearsvn/trunk/src/).

The [script](http://clearsvn.open.collab.net/source/browse/*checkout*/clearsvn/trunk/src/clearsvn.py?revision=44&content-type=text/plain) [usage page](http://clearsvn.open.collab.net/source/browse/*checkout*/clearsvn/trunk/src/clearsvn_modules/PrintUsage.py?revision=29&content-type=text/plain) seems to use an example like:

```
clearsvn export -s D:\\svnstuff\\client3\\our_project \\
                       -t \\trunk -c M:\\Bob_view\\the_vob\\our_project \\
                       -v med
```

That means you need a simple [dynamic view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2925378/6309) with a simple default config spec:

```
element * /main/LATEST
```

> we have two branches , `main` and `dev` and we are using base ClearCase.

That would mean 2 dynamic ClearCase views, and two `clearsvn export`.
The second ClearCase view would have a simple config spec:

```
element * .../dev/LATEST
element * /main/LATEST
```

The question is: when would you call those clearsvn commands?
I wouldn't recommend calling them automatically in a postop checkin trigger, because that would call that export process for *each version* of *each file* checked in into ClearCase.
I would rather import it each time I set a label (with the idea the content referenced by that label is supposed to be a coherent one, worthy of export as an SVN revision).

Comment: we have two branches , main and dev and we are using base clearcase.

Comment: @user2636464 then you need two ClearCase dynamic views, one set for each branch, and two `clearsvn export` process that you trigger regularly.

Comment: what I would like to do is to export the changes to SVN whenever there is some code change in clearcase dev branch.but not vice-versa

Comment: @user2636464 that is precisely what I mention in my answer: clearsvn export exports changes from ClearCase to SNV: *not* vice-versa. And I mention to *not* do that export for *every* changes, because it doesn't make change to make an SVN revision for each file modification from ClearCase.