# what is the diff between vob storage host path name and global pathname

Tags: clearcase

I am using base clearcase 7.0 and recently we backed up our vob storage to netapp

Now when I desc a vob, it shows global path as the backup server path:

VOB storage host:pathname "vob_server:/mmm/ClearCase/vob_storage/xxx.vbs"
   VOB storage global pathname "\netapp\vob_storage\xxx.vbs"

And lsvob -l gives:

```
Global path: \\netapp\vob_storage\xxx.vbs
Server host: vob_server

Vob on host: vob_server
Vob server access path: /mmm/ClearCase/vob_storage/xxx.vbs
```

Can anyone explain why global pathname for vob is netapp (where vob is getting backed up). When users are accessing vob , they are accessing it from netapp or vob_server.

Please help and let me get out of my confusion :(

Answer (score 2):

VOBs can be thought of as having two major components, the VOB database and the set of storage pools.  The storage pools are where the *contents* of versioned files (and shared derived objects) are stored.  The VOB database is where the configuration management metadata (ex. labels, baselines, version trees, ...) are stored.

Clients never access the VOB database (DB) directly.  They always access the metadata through server processes running on the "VOB server host" machine.  Thus, only these VOB server processes need to know the path to the DB (the "host path" or "Vob server access path") and that location does not need to be on a network share.

If you're using CCLC (the ClearCase Local Client where dynamic and snapshot views live), the storage pools are typically accessed directly over NFS or SMB.  Thus, the storage pools must exist on a network share that is accessible "globally" on the LAN (the "Global path").

ClearCase normally creates the VOB DB directory and the storage pool directories as siblings under the "VOB storage directory".  If the VOB storage directory is on a NAS, the VOB server processes still have to run on a "VOB server host" machine (ex. on a Windows Server 2008 or Solaris 10 machine, in your example, the machine called "vob_server") but the global path to the storage pools is is a path directly to the share on the NAS (i.e. under \netapp\vob_storage...).

Note that in your example, the VOB server processes running on the host, "vob_server", are accessing the VOB DB at "/mmm/ClearCase/vob_storage/xxx.vbs".  This implies that either (1) 'netapp's share has been mounted at "/mmm/ClearCase" or (2) the VOB creator placed the VOB DB on a local file system at "/mmm/ClearCase" and only the storage pools for that VOB on the NAS.

Answer (score 1):

> When users are accessing vob

They are accessing from their hard drive [(view snapshot) or from the dynamic view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2925378/6309) mounting point (`M:\aVob` or `/view/myview/vobs/aVob`)

But in both cases, they need for their view_server to be able to access the vob storage:
the VOB storage *global* pathname path is there for those users: they will use `netapp`.

If a user isn't able to list the content of  `\netapp\vob_storage\xxx.vbs` from a shell, the vob won't be accessible in his/her views.

See "[ClearCase VOB properties](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrc.help.doc/topics/u_props_vob.htm)" and "[vob administration](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.books.cc_admin.doc/rgy-admin.htm)":

Global path:

> The network path name, relative to the ClearCase Web server, to the VOB storage directory on the VOB server host.
>
> A network pathname to the VOB storage directory, expressed in a form that is **valid for all hosts that access the VOB.**
> This pathname (referred to as a global path) is used by client programs that need network access to the VOB storage directory.