# ClearCase: Unable to create directory when trying use 'startview' on Linux

Tags: linux, clearcase

I am really stuck in ClearCase startview on Linux. I tried the below:

```
ct startview <viewtag>
```

And met an issue like below:

> cleartool: Error: Unable to create directory "": error detected by ClearCase subsystem.

I am sure the view is OK, and I can start it in other host. So perhaps my OS met some issue. Is there some good solution?

And I have restarted my Linux system.

Answer (score 1):

If this is about a [*dynamic* view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2925378/6309), you can check [technote swg21449500 "Create and startview errors: Cannot start dynamic view and Unable to create directory"](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21449500):

#### Cause

> The client or view-server installation is corrupted. The symptoms would typically be seen immediately after applying a Fix Pack of iFix.

#### Diagnosing the problem

> A `cleartool -verall` showing a mismatch between the MVFS and the other modules is a clear indication of corruption.

#### Resolving the problem

> An uninstall and re-install on the machine will be necessary to resolve the issue.

---

On Windows, you can see a similar error when a Windows client attempts to start a dynamic view on a Linux or UNIX server running Samba.
See [swg21295394](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21295394).

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I have tried ct -verall and there's no mismatch between the MVFS and the other modules. And Samba's version is version 3.

Comment: @Cheers but if your client is Linux, you don't care about Samba anyway. What is the version of ClearCase you are using? Is it a dynamic view you are starting? Is /views present at the root of your Linux?

Comment: The version of clearcase is 7.1.2.5. And the view is exactly a dynamic view. /views is present at the root.

Comment: @Cheers Then you might find more clues in the log ([`cleartool getlog`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_getlog.htm)). Check also if the services like `albd_server` is running (otherwise: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21131088)

Comment: I checked the log and perhaps this is the point: mvfs(0): Error: View op nil failed for <NULL>:<NULL> -  RPC timed out. Do you have any solution. Otherwis the albd service is running oK. Thanks

Comment: A bit as in https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014232707, the first thing to check is: can you reproduce that same issue (on your same Linux client) with another existing view? with a new dynamic view? If no, I would recommend, in the interest of moving forward, to create a new view with the same config spec, delete the current one and use the new one.

Comment: yeah, I met the same issue in all views. And also I met similiar issue when I tried to start a new-created view in the same view server but OK with a new-created view in local-host.

Comment: @Cheers so you mean the view storage path, when local, means the view works, but when the view storage path is a network one, it won't work, right? Then the issue should be where those view storages reside.

Comment: yes, kind of. but other host can start the view. I am not sure if the MVFS service met some issue.

Comment: @Cheers this should be limited to an issue with the local MVFS driver then. Uninstalling and re-installing ClearCase on that Linux client should solve the issue.

Comment: thanks for your advice, but the host is just not a personal one so it's not convienent to re-install ClearCase.

Comment: @Cheers surely your IT support team can do that for you (it has root access, and can perform that quickly.) That won't have any effect on your current views, merges, deliver or rebase.