# How to Create a Dynamic view in ClearCase 8 on Machine where I dont have ClearCase Server installed?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm, clearcase-remote-client

I need to create a Dynamic view on a machine where I have installed only ClearCase 8.0 client. I have ClearCase 8.0 server installed on another machine and my requirement is to have dynamic view on both server and client to be in sync. on Server i have already created the Dynamic view but not able to create the same(may be with same name) on Client machine.

This is basically required to execute the lsactivity command using the cleartool command to get the list of files associated with the specific activity and then I need to fetch only those files from the server repository to my snapshot view which is on client machine.

Answer (score 0):

> but not able to create the same(may be with same name) on Client machine.

This is normal: the view registry contains is based on the name of the views as id.

You should be able to [start your dynamic view](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v8r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrc.help.doc/topics/t_start_dynamic_view.htm) on the client if the view storage is accessible from said client (and you are on [a LAN, not WAN](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v8r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.help.ic.doc/topics/c_whatsnew.htm)).

If not, the easiest way to go forward is to create a second dynamic view, with a different name but with the same config spec.
As they are both [*dynamic* views](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2925378/6309), they will be in sync.

Comment: Do we have any specific steps to create dynamic view on the machine other than the ClearCase server hosting machine?

Comment: And for your reference my both machines are on Cloud so not sure if they are on LAN or WAN. Your comments are most welcome.

Comment: @SatishThaokar you need to mount a vob, for a dynamic view to show anything. See http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v8r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrc.help.doc%2Ftopics%2Ft_mount_vob.htm

Comment: yes I mounted that. I have question What do you mean by "Thick" ClearCase Client?

Comment: @SatishThaokar I didn't use "thick client" in my answer. It is a pre-CC8.0 term, where you had a "thick client" (full ClearCase), and a "light client" (CCRC, CC Remote Client).