# Intellij and Clearcase: Performing VCS refresh takes too long

Tags: intellij-idea, clearcase

I am using IntelliJ 12 and am seeing some strange problems around Clearcase.

I am knew to IntelliJ so perhaps I've missed some configuration.

Every time I attempt to check in a file, I get the attached popup which appears on my screen for minutes. I can click Skip to hide it, but I don't understand why it takes so long.

Also, when I have a file that is in Clearcase but not yet checked out, when I click on the Clearcase menu I get the option to Check In even after a refresh. This makes no sense and is quite confusing.

Therefore, I'm wondering if the Clearcase plugin is stable, or if I'm missing some config.

[image]

Comment: did you manage to solve this?

Comment: No, thankfully we switched to using Git. IntelliJ's Clearcase support is very poor

Comment: Intellij sucks at svn, git etc, use some 3rd party tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before advising you to log an issue on that [IntelliJ ClearCase plugin](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/search/index?pr=idea&search=clearcase), check if you aren't using a dynamic view.

IntelliJ does a lot of code parsing, and that can take times in a dynamic view (network access), as opposed to a snapshot view (local disk access).

See "[What are the differences between a snapshot view and a dynamic view?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2925378/6309)".

Comment: No, I am not using a dynamic view, it is a snapshot

Comment: @DJ180 then it is an issue to report to the appriate Jira page for that plugin.

Comment: Will report back on what IntelliJ provide me with