# Clearcase BASE url of a file from a CI trigger

Tags: triggers, clearcase

I have a file `foo.c` and I quickly want to access it's BASE version. How can I do it?

For example I have `foo.c@@/main/2`

`$ENV{'CLEARCASE_PN'}` gives me the current file path: `L:/user/vob/dir/foo.c`

`$ENV{'CLEARCASE_XPN'}` gives me the next version number `L:/user/vob/dir/foo.c@@/main/3`

How can I quickly open the current base version on the current view `foo.c@@/main/2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$ENV{'CLEARCASE_XPN'}` should give you the *extended* path name of the current version, as selected by the current view, not the "next" version.

Here "base" is for the current version before a CI trigger allows a new one to be created.

In that case, cleartool descr -l $ENV{'CLEARCASE_PN'} should still display the one selected by the current view `foo.c@@/main/2`.

If not, using '`-pred`' would help (to get the previous version): `cleartool descr -pred -l $ENV{'CLEARCASE_PN'}`

The [OP coin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2612235/coin) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26882643/clearcase-base-url-of-a-file-from-a-ci-trigger/26882856?noredirect=1#comment42322561_26882856):

```perl
my $desc = 'cleartool descr $ENV{'CLEARCASE_PN'}'; 
if($desc =~ /predecessor version:\s*(.+)$/) { 
    die "Predecessor: $ENV{'CLEARCASE_PN'}\@\@$1"; 
}
```

---

"base" could be interpreted as the base contributor version for a merge (see "[How to perform a 'merge' using clearcase?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24018727/6309)")

In that case, you can check:

- [`cleartool findmerge -print`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/redirect/cchelp/v7r1m2/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_findmerge.htm), which can list the names of the versions that require a merge. The default listing includes the version IDs of the to-versions and from-versions and the version ID of the base contributor (common ancestor)
- [`cleartool describe -anc`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/api/redirect/cchelp/v7r1m2/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_describe.htm), which is able to desribe the closest common ancestor version of all the pname arguments.

Comment: Unfortunately in a CI trigger, `CLEARCASE_XPN` seems different. I guess another "pre-op" trigger already did the check-in.

Comment: @coin right, in that context, that make sense. But a `cleartool descr $ENV{'CLEARCASE_PN'}` should display the current version (are we talking about a pre-op or post-op trigger though?)

Comment: I am always getting confused with pre-op and post-op triggers. Do you have documentation on it?

Comment: @coin no, it is just part of the mktrtrype you must have used (an option)

Comment: @coin in the meantime, what does a `cleartool descr $ENV{'CLEARCASE_PN'}` would return in your script called by your trigger?

Comment: Actually this gives me what I need: `my $desc = 'cleartool descr $ENV{'CLEARCASE_PN'}'; if($desc =~ /predecessor version:\s*(.+)$/) {
    die "Predecessor: $ENV{'CLEARCASE_PN'}\@\@$1";
}`

Comment: @coin Excellent. I have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: @nowox Remember, I am here every. single. day: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122976/anyone-with-a-visited-3333-days-3333-consecutive-in-their-profile#comment1065955_122976

Comment: Among everything I learned from SO, this was a comment you made that I will never forget. I’ll never stop to amaze me.