# Are there problems with using a Dynamic View in RAD 7.5?

Tags: clearcase, websphere-7, file-sharing, developer-tools, ibm-rad-7.5

Our team recently switched from using WSED 5.2 to using RAD 7.5 for our code development (we're a little behind the curve in development software).  This, as well as a move to a WAS 7 server, is a mandatory move for us to complete, so moving to a different developer or server is not an option.

Since moving to this new developer, I've been having problems making changes to the app and testing them on my local server.  Refreshing the server doesn't help, nor does a Clean or a Publish to the server.  Even clearing and rebuilding the projects doesn't seem to do the trick.  The only thing that does allow me to view and test code changes with 100% reliability is a complete system reset followed by a clean and rebuild of the project - which obviously is not what we were hoping for with the new developer tool.

It occurs to me that it may have something to do with my code view - we're using a ClearCase code sharing system, and by choice we decided to try using a Dynamic View for my code, because we thought it would be great and fast and dynamic at the time.  But now, looking at the problems I'm having just testing the code, I'm wondering if it was a mistake to use a Dynamic View.

Are there any reported problems with using Dynamic View on a file-shared coding project with RAD 7.5 that we should be aware of?  And are there any fixes for it?  Please note that while it wouldn't be ideal, 'switch to static view' would be an acceptable 'soultion'.

Comment: Get the files from cleareCase to clean, separate directory, not managed by clearcase and check, if you have same behavior. If everything would work fine, then I'd suggest to opening ticket in ClearCase support or just switch to different source control system like svn or github.

Answer (score 1):

If you operations involves not just punctual read access, but massive read/write operation, I would recommend using a **[snapshot view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2925378/6309)**, and see if the issue persists.

You can customize the load rules in order to load in said snapshot view only what you need.

Comment: Judging by the answer, snapshot view would be better for code that has to be tested and re-tested constantly. So...what are the benefits to dynamic view, if changing the code is such a headache?  Also, why would IBM say that Dynamic views offer 'fast immediate updates' if this is not even close to the case? http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21177694

Comment: @Zibbobz dynamic views are quickly accessing *large* set of files. But once you start to compile in it, this isn't very efficient.