# Will "Deliver Stream" connect my local code to a ClearCase stream?

Tags: version-control, clearcase, ibm-rad-7.5

I am trying to connect my code to a ClearCase Stream.  Currently I'm operating under the belief that, once connected to ClearCase, the "Deliver Stream" activity from the drop-down menu will perform this task.

However, all the literature I have read is *just* vague enough that it isn't clear if this will overwrite the code that is currently in that stream, or if that code will overwrite the code that is currently in my workspace.

I do not want to lose my workspace code, nor do I want to overwrite my ClearCase code if I can help it.

Will this "Deliver Stream" activity do either of these things?  And, more importantly, will it actually connect my code to source control?

If not, and this is really the heart of my question, **then how do I connect my RAD 7.5 workspace to a ClearCase source controlled file sharing system**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't affect your workspace, but I would recommend doing those operations outside of RAD first, to be sure of what is actually taking place:

> I am trying to connect my code to a ClearCase Stream

First: is your code versioned in ClearCase in the first place: is your workspace part of a (snapshot) ClearCase view attached to an UCM Stream?

If not, you need to create an [UCM dynamic view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1367656/6309) attached to the right stream, and [use `clearfsimport` to add your files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/144310/6309).

Once the import is done, create a snapshot view on the same stream to be used in RAD (since, [as I mentioned in your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24390000/are-there-problems-with-using-a-dynamic-view-in-rad-7-5#comment37727440_24390664), dynamic views aren't well suited for compilation)

---

> if this will overwrite the code that is currently in that stream, or if that code will overwrite the code that is currently in my workspace

A [Deliver Stream](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rsmhelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.rational.clearcase.help/doc/DelivDev.htm) is about:

> deliver and integrate change sets to the integration stream once an activity has been completed.
>   For example, if your task was to create a new feature `A`, you can deliver a change set relating only to new feature `A` into the integration stream.

That means your current workspace represents a snapshot view loaded and attached to a *child* stream "`FeatureA`", and "Deliver Stream" would trigger **[an UCM deliver](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1643968/6309)** between your current (child-)stream `FeatureA` and the parent `Integration` stream.

See more at "[Integration stream vs integration view in ClearCase](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9880031/6309)".

---

If you do a "Deliver Stream" from RAD:

> As you deliver your changes to a stream, **we suggest that you have two different instances of Rational Application Developer open**:
>
> - one workspace will have your development workspace which contains the complete changes,
> - and the other will have the integration workspace open.
>
> If you invoke the Deliver Stream option from the integration workspace, your changes automatically appear in the workspace.
>   If you deliver from your development workspace, you will have modified the file system outside of Rational Application Developer.

Comment: To answer your first question: No, that is in fact *exactly* what I'm trying to do with my code right now.  It is...not cooperating as well as I would hope.

Comment: @Zibbobz That is different then: you need to import your files in a view set on the right stream. See my modified answer and its links.

Comment: I'm still having trouble connecting my workspace to source control. I have the dynamic view, the snapshot view, and a blank workspace.  I set up RAD 7.5 to be compatable with ClearCase SCM and UMC, connect to clearcase, and then import Existing project into RAD from the location of my Snapshot view, but once I do, the files are clearly not part of source control (I can't check them out, hijack them, or perform any team activities).  So I'm not sure what to do after that.

Comment: @Zibbobz forget RAD for now: first clearfsimport your sources, then import your project into RAD. First ClearCase, then RAD.

Comment: I've already done that.  I have the dynamic view right in front of me full of File element version files.

Comment: @Zib Then, make sure your snapshot view is updated, and that is include your .project and .classpath. You need to import into your RAD project a .project which is directly part of the ClearCase snapshot view for the integration to work.

Comment: I believe you have sufficiently answered my question, but I still have trouble connecting to the Snapshot and to source in my desired workspace, so rather than continue this in comments, I'm opening up a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24555564/connecting-a-snapshot-view-to-clearcase-in-rad-7-5