# Connecting a Snapshot View to Clearcase in RAD 7.5

Tags: clearcase, ibm-rad-7.5

I need some help connecting my RAD 7.5 workspace to a ClearCase source-controlled snapshot view.

Here is what I have done so far.

- **Creating a stream of the code in ClearCase** - Done.
- **Creating a dynamic view of the code in ClearCase** - Done.
- **Checking all files into source** - Done, every file is part of the "File Element Version" in ClearCase for this dynamic view.
- **Connect a Worspace to the Dynamic View** - I don't know if this is necessary, but I have managed to do this.  And no, I do not remember what I did *exactly* to make it connect to the source.
- **Create a snapshot view from the source** - Done.  In ClearCase Explorer, under "Exploring ClearCase Projects", I right-click to stream of my code and choose "Create View", then specifically select "create Dynamic View" and "Snapshot", then choose a local c:/ccviews/ folder for my source to be created in, then choose the source components to be loaded into that view.
- **Create a new workspace for this Snapshot View** - Done.
- **Set up the Snapshot View for a ClearCase Connection** Done, I open "Preferences" under the "Windows" Dropdown, expand "General", select "Capabilities", go to "Advanced Options", expand "Team", and make sure that UCM and SCM ClearCase Adapter are bot checkmarked.
- **Connect to ClearCase** - Done.
- **Import the project** - Done. I select "Import" from the File dropdown, expand "General", select "Existing Projects Into Workspace", select c:/ccviews/[Folder containing my project], check the "copy projects into workspace" box, and hit OK.
- **Run the migration tool** - Done.

So with that all complete, I still cannot connect to my source.  I KNOW that ClearCase is connected, and that I can connect a workspace to the source because my Dynamic View is connected to said source, but the Dynamic View is not ideal for the read/write testing that I need to do.

I can publish my code to a WAS7 server, but that wont' do me much good if I can't make changes to it. I've tried rebasing my stream but it wont' let me, nor will it let me do a deliver stream action.

So what now do I need to do to complete the connection of my workspace to my source?

As requested, here are pictures of my Eclipse workspace, and my Clearcase screen with .project and .classpath files shown.

[image]
Larger Size: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLPoK.png

[image]
Larger Size: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtIFP.png

Comment: What ClearCase version are you using?

Comment: @VonC Rationa ClearCase Explorer 7.1.0.7, according to the "about" part of my ClearCase help menu.

Comment: Did you try the import project in the ClearCase perspective (https://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrc.help.doc/topics/t_ccrc_eclipse_import_psf.htm)

Comment: I suppose the adaptor is fully enabled? (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21252464#Enabling%20CC%20SCM%20Adapter%20for%20v7) or activated (http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rsmhelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.rational.clearcase.help/doc/Activate.htm

Comment: @VonC I believe the adapter is fully enabled.  I am not sure, however, how to import the project in the ClearCase 'perspective', since no such perspective is available on my RAD 7.5, and I'm not sure where to locate our .psf file.

Comment: I confirm there is no `.psf` file involved (it was just part of the documentation I was linking to)

Comment: Can you add a screenshot with what you see in your Eclipse workspace. And a screenshot of your file explorer showing where your sources are, along with the `.project` and `.classpath`.

Comment: @VonC I've added the pictures as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can try is open your RAD with a different Eclipse workspace, and try and import your project (from the snapsphot view this time) in that new Eclipse workspace.

I would recommend also stopping the dynamic view (just to be on the safe side, even though both should be able to run together)

```
cleartool endview -server my_dynamic_view_tag
```

Comment: @Zibbobz is your `.project`/`.classpath` Eclipse project versioned and present amongst the files in the snapshot view?

Comment: It is present, but I don't know how to 'version' it to my workspace/view, if that is necessary to do before importing it/after importing it.

Comment: @Zibbobz no, you don't have to version it, just wanted to be sure the eclipse project files are part of the snapshot view.

Comment: @Zibbobz when you have completed the import, and right-click on a file, sub-menu Team, do you see ClearCase options like checkout, version tree and so on?

Comment: No, I do not.  The only options I see are "Apply Patch" and "Show Local History".  The options "Show Activities" and "Share Projects" are also there, but greyed out, and there are no other options under Team.

Comment: The strange thing is, I am able to check out files in this manner in my workspace connected to the Dynamic View, but even when I stop that view in my Dynamic workspace, the snapshot view workspace still can't check out these files.