# Can Rational Application Developer v9.0 Integrate with CCRC 7.1.2?

Tags: eclipse, clearcase, ibm-rad, clearcase-remote-client

I am unable to find any definitive documentation on how to integrate IBM Rational Application Developer v9.0 with ClearCase Remote Client server v7.1.2. My questions are: is this possible? and how can it be done? Most of the compatibility charts published by IBM appear to be out of date and do not reference RAD v9.

I have been able to use the Eclipse ClearCase plugin found on SourceForge. However, solutions based on cleartool commands have proven to be somewhat sluggish in the WAN environment in which I am working. My attempts to install the CCRC plugin in RAD 9 result in dependency conflicts and attempts to install the CCRC extension via IBM installation manager result in generic error message saying that a conflict exists.

Can this be done? It seems as though the Installation Manager offerings for CCRC shown here (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21432752) *should* work with RAD, but I'm wondering if RAD 9 is too new for CCRC v7.1.2. There is no confirmation of that anywhere that I have been able to located, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integration between a classic ClearCase and RAD is already shaky (see the recent question "[Connecting a Snapshot View to Clearcase in RAD 7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24555564/6309)")

So to my knowledge, no, there is no official integration, because [`rcleartool`](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24021929) or the [java CM API](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21566474) isn't yet fully integrated in a RAD-compatible CCRC plugin.

RAD 9 is the most recent RAD, and only a recent CCRc (the ClearTeam 8.X, with its rcleartool or CM API) would be a cancidate for integration.
CCRC 7.1.x seems too old for integrating with such a recent RAD.

Comment: I added some additional information with a link to the IBM repository list. Based on what I have seen, it appears that CCRC should integrated with RAD products on some level, specifically using the "extension" installed via Installation Manager (as opposed to the plugin installed using Eclipse updater).

Comment: @MGE true, but CCRC is now called ClearTeam 8.x, and I suspect only a recent version of CCRC (meaning ClearTeam 8.x) would be candidate for any integration with a recent version of RAD (RAD v9.0.x is based on Eclipse 4.2.2+ plus Web Tools Project (WTP) 3.4.2+ plus bugzilla patches)

Comment: That certainly seems to be the case, I agree. It would be nice if IBM would put that in plain view somewhere rather than leave us guessing based on generic/non-descriptive error messages. CCRC 7.1.2 still seems to be maintained as well.