# Clearcase UCM. Unable to deliver

Tags: clearcase-ucm

I created a new development stream out of an Integration stream. On the dev stream I created a dynamic view and an activity. I then added a new directory to an existing directory using `clearfsimport`.

e.g. `cd` to the parent directory where I want to add the new `dir`. then run:

`clearfsimport -recurse -follow -nsetevent -c "adding new version" ~/newdir` .

When it's all done I try to deliver the activity using clearcase project explorer. This throws an error like so:

```
"Merge Manager: warning: Element xxxx is not visible in view <Integration view name>
... ... ... 
If this element should be visible cancel this operation, fix the prolem, and re-run the operation"
```

I have been doing this every week for months now and never had an issue. I'm really not sure what am I missing here or how to fix it. If it helps, the mastership of the Integration stream was transfered from a remote replica to ours. All my previous delivers were on the remote replica. But now I have complete mastership over the integration stream.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the nature of the target view (the one in which you are doing the deliver, the one associated with the integration stream): [snapshot or dynamic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2925378/6309).

You would need to check if the parent folder of `xxxx` is correctly checked out (or if you *can* check it out).
A `cleartool ls` in that parent  folder of 'xxx' in the target (integration) view can help to test if everything seems ok.

If you are using a snapshot view, a cleartool update *before* the deliver can help too.

Answer (score 0):

Since the integration stream mastership has just been transferred from a remote replica to your site, I would suggest the following:

1) Make sure you have created a view associated to the integration stream on your site

2) Make sure that the default delivery view is set to your integration view. You might need to reset it using the command

> cleartool deliver -reset -to *your-integration-view*

The command above has to be launched from your development view.

I suggest you have a look at the [cleartool deliver command](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_deliver.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.0%2F9-1-0-2-6)