# Clearcase find out view type

Tags: version-control, clearcase

What's the simplest way to know if my view is a snapshot view or dynamic view?

`lstype` doesn't help.

```
[tthangavel@wtl-lbuild-4 fw]$ cleartool lstype myview
cleartool: Error: Pathname not found: "myview".
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, for "the simplest way", I would go with:

```
cleartool lsview -l myview
```

The resulting output may include:

```
View attributes: snapshot,ucmview,webview
```

If it does not say `snapshot`, then it's a dynamic view.

From the manual, [Rational ClearCase command reference - lsview](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_7.1.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lsview.htm)

With the –full option, reports the following additional properties:

- When and by whom view-private data was last accessed
- When and by whom a view-private object was last updated
- When and by whom the config spec was last updated
- For a dynamic view, when and by whom a derived object was last created, promoted, and winked in
- For a dynamic view, whether it creates shareable derived objects or nonshareable derived objects  The view's text mode
- **Whether the view is a dynamic view, snapshot view, or a web view**
- Whether the view is read-only or writable

ps: Yes, I indicate use the command `-l/ong`, but the documented explanation is the section for properties `–pro/perties [ –ful/l | –text_mode ]`; blame IBM.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Its path.

```
cleartool pwd
```

If it starts with /view or M:\, it  is a dynamic view.
If not, it is a snapshot view.

Also the presence of load rules in its config spec:

```
cleartool catcs|grep load
```

There is never any load rules in a dynamic view.

See more at "[What are the differences between a snapshot view and a dynamic view?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2925378/6309)".