# clear case views partition is not showing free space even after deleting view private files

Tags: clearcase, diskspace

We are using ClearCase which has dedicated disk partition to host cc views.
The disk got full after checking, a view private file which was of 2.4gb was deleted. Even after deleting that, we are not able to perform checkout operation. It is saying that no disk space is available.

```
bash-3.00# du -sh /ccviews1/ 

3.7G   /ccviews1

bash-3.00# df -k /ccviews1/

Filesystem            kbytes    used   avail capacity  Mounted on

/dev/dsk/c1t1d0s6    6960077 6890479       0   100%    /ccviews1
```

When I checked the size of partition, it is 3.7GB. But, disk filesystem command is not showing that empty space.

Please help me sort this out.

Comment: What ClearCase version are you using? What OS are you using on the client side, on the server side?

Comment: It is V8.0.1 and the OS on the server side is Solaris10 and client side, Windows 7.

Comment: OK, and did you already add to source control that big file? Or did you delete it *before* adding it to source control?

Answer (score 0):

> a view private file which was of 2.4gb was deleted.

It depends on how it was deleted. If it was already added to source control, its history would remain.

Its local deletion would affect the view storage only if the view is a [dynamic one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2925378/6309) (in which case private elements are indeed stored in the associated view storage of the view).

Answer (score 0):

Let's see:
- Solaris
- Local disk or SAN partition.

What filesystem is this? Also, is it really only 6.8GB?

Anyway, you may want to check out this link on serverfault:

https://serverfault.com/questions/501963/how-to-recover-free-space-on-deleted-files-without-restarting-the-referencing-pr

If the du and df outputs sho different "used" values, you likely have deleted files still in use by processes... They won't show up in a directory scan, but they're still in use...