# C# Socket and ClearCase Dynamic View issue

Tags: c#, sockets, windows-7, clearcase, dynamic-view

I have a project under source control and I'm using a dynamic view. This project uses sockets. When I run the program I get an exception using this line of code:

```
var addresses = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName());
```

I get a socket exception with the following information:
Error Code: 11003
Message: "A non-recoverable error occurred during a database lookup" 
Socket Error Code: NonRecovery

I don't have this issue running locally or on another windows network share (non-Clearcase). I believe this is a security issue related to sockets and network drives. I have a workaround but would really like to resolve this issue. I'm on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first workaround would be to use a [snapshot view instead of a dynamic one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2925378/6309).

That way, you would be directly on the C drive instead of an MVFS mount point.

If you have to use dynamic view, make sure it is being accessed through its full path (no subst, no setview): `M:\myview\myVob\...`

Finally, it can depend on your exact ClearCase version: with ClearCase 7.x, there was socket error on Windows before: see "[Unable to run executable that opens a socket on Microsoft Windows Vista, Windows Server 2008 or Windows 7](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21405894)"

Comment: Thank you! I was aware of the snapshot option but did find I was using CC version 7.x