# VCS settings for Clear Case UCM Plugin for Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, clearcase-ucm

I am using Jenkins and its ClearCase UCM plugin, but am unable to make it work (make ClearCase checkout the proper view in the Jenkins job workspace).

I have been trying to set up source code to ClearCase, but it is asking too many inputs and I am not aware what to fill.
It is asking for the following fields:

```
Viewtag : Jenkins_${USER_NAME}_${NODE_NAME}_${JOB_NAME}${DASH_WORKSPACE_NUMBER}
View Path: 
Stream Selector.
```

Can anybody help with this?

[image: fields]

What should be the correct values for ClearCase to work properly, that is get the code in the Jenkins job workspace?

Comment: Note to moderator: this is not off topic. This is not a request for a tool recommendation.

Comment: Exactly. How can this be off topic.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev Thank you for this feedback, you are right. I have edited the question (and deleted my previous comments to clean up this question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [JENKINS ClearCase UCM Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/ClearCase+UCM+Plugin), like any other VCS (Version Control System) Jenkins plugin, needs to access the sources in order for Jenkins to checkout said sources in a Jenkins workspace.

For that:

> The plugin will automatically create a snapshot view in a folder named 'view' in the root of the job's workspace.
>   Snapshot views can - [as opposed to dynamic views](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2925378/6309) - be located anywhere, which we exploit to place it inside the job's workspace.
>   Dynamic Views can only reside on the location where your mvfs is located and that is not inside the workspace.

It should not ask for the field you mention.

Instead:

The ClearCase UCM plugin introduces several build variables:

- `CC_BASELINE` the baseline being build
- `CC_VIEWTAG` the view tag
- `CC_VIEWPATH` the path of the view(the same as `%WORKSPACE%\view`)

You can setup a job using that plugin by making it monitor changes in your ClearCase UCM VOBs by polling for new baselines on a given stream.

From the comments, the default value for those field is fine, and Jenkins will create a dynamic view accessing the UCM components if the stream mentioned in the settings of that plugin.

[image: https://wiki.jenkins.io/download/attachments/58001105/ccucm_config.png?version=1&modificationDate=1439193524000&api=v2]

Comment: HI I am able to download the code but the code which is getting downloaded is .VWS. Any idea how can i extract files from it?

Comment: @rajvardhan only a dynamic view can give you access to those files, unless they are private.

Comment: Hi I am able to find the code. Just one question though. Can i download 2 projects using clearcase plugin

Comment: @rajvardhan Not easiley, unless they are part of the same UCM component.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot for your help. Now my code is downloading from Jenkins. But i have another question on how to run a DB script using Jenkins.

Comment: Hi,

I am able to download code from clear case using Jenkins. 
Now I am trying to run a SQL script from Jenkins.
Please see my configuration below:

 
 
When I am running the same script from command prompt it runs but through Jenkins I am getting the following error:

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on Mon Sep 17 16:12:40 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified


Enter user-name:

Do you have an idea what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks,
Raj Vardhan

Comment: @rajvardhan I would be best to open a new question, with more detail in it.