# Create the snapshot view in clearcase

Tags: clearcase

I'm in process of creating snapshot view , I refer to [the post "Proper 'cleartool mkview' for ClearCase Snapshot view creation"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207409/proper-cleartool-mkview-for-clearcase-snapshot-view-creation)

It helped.

But now I don't know what server/shared location i must use to create the views. Can I get those details from any of the existing views I already have ( created through ClearCase client)

Comment: ok. able to see with the command >cleartool lsview -long view_name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From any view, you can:

```
cd /path/to/my/view
cleartool lsview -l -full -pro -cview
```

That will give you all the details you need.

See:

- [`cleartool lsview`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lsview.htm) for more on this command
- [**`cleartool lsstgloc`**](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lsstgloc.htm)  for more on the view storage you may have declared.